# Scraping multiple cryptocurrencies

Tags: altcoin

I would like to scrap data from Bitcoin and mix of alternative cryptocurrencies which are fundamentally like Bitcoin. The data I am looking for are blocks and transactions.

I found a pretty awesome (very old and not maintained) project called MultiCoin: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=24209.0

I have noticed cool projects such as DNS Seeding which do things like connect to peer nodes simply to request more peer nodes (without transmitting data), but do not seem to transmit transactions or blocks or any other data.

Are there any more modern implementations of this? As the alternate cryptocurrency space grows I would like to get data from a lot of coins without having to consume more resources than strictly necessary.

Comment: The obvious way to collect blocks and transactions is to just run a client for each coin. If that is not feasible, can you explain why? Also, I don't really see what DNS seeding has to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

The [BlockCypher web services](http://www.blockcypher.com) supports 3 different cryptocurrencies right now, more may be added in the future. All coins have the exact same services exposed so it's easy to develop for all of them at once.